# Using kazoo (zookeeper client) in django

Tags: django, apache-zookeeper, kazoo

I was wondering if someone could point me to an example of using kazoo within a Django application. My use case is to use kazoo to retrieve a list of values, and process them, within a request cycle.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nd_service_registry for that, you get the list of values once, and nd_service_registry will take care of updating this list (that is in memory) whenever the values in zookeeper are updated.
So you will gaurantee that the list is always up-to-date

https://github.com/Nextdoor/ndserviceregistry

Installation and instantiation is explained in the github repo ^